# Export Attendance SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like get help in the following Data. We have hand punch machines which saves exit and entry log, each exit and entry log stores a different row for an employee.

Table:

| Date | circuit_label | Fisr_name | Last_name | Logical_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-04 07:45:24 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Alh | Yousef | 24 |
| 2023-10-04 08:11:38 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Mon | Ivan | 01 |
| 2023-10-04 08:16:02 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Al | Omar | 66 |
| 2023-10-04 08:27:20 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Sar | Mahmod | 121 |
| 2023-10-04 10:42:22 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Imr | M | 02 |
| 2023-10-04 11:18:48 | Access 1 AC00GF-07-796 | Imr | M | 02 |
| 2023-10-04 11:33:40 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Imr | M | 02 |
| 2023-10-04 15:45:24 | Access 2 AC00GF-07-796 | Alh | Yousef | 24 |

I would like to get the time in and time out for a single day . As you can see this is the time in and time out for a day, but it stores two records . So in this regard I am quite confused how to tackle this.

Want to export:

| In_time | Out_time | Fisr_name | Last_name | Logical_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-04 07:45:24 | 2023-10-04 15:45:24 | Alh | Yousef | 24 |
| 2023-10-04 08:11:38 | the employee hasn't left yet | Mon | Ivan | 01 |
| 2023-10-04 08:16:02 | the employee hasn't left yet | Al | Omar | 66 |
| 2023-10-04 08:27:20 | the employee hasn't left yet | Sar | Mahmod | 121 |
| 2023-10-04 10:42:22 | 2023-10-04 11:33:40 | Imr | M | 02 |

Comment: Can you please take the time to format your data so that its readable. Even better provide it as DDL+DML so it can be tested against. And we would like to see what you have tried.

Comment: I hope you also realise the risk you are taking running such an old, unsupported version of SQL Server.

Comment: I formated it as table how is appear to you? regarding my progress still searching to find a solution :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just wrote :
SELECT Date,circuit_label,Fisr_name,Last_name,Logical_code FROM test WHERE ((circuit_label IN (901)) OR (circuit_label IN (800)) OR (circuit_label IN (985))
 OR (circuit_label IN (864)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just need to `group by Fisr_name, Last_name, Logical_code` the results of the query that filtered by the date interval of your preference and then find the `min` and `max` `Date` for your groups:

```
select min(Date) as In_time, max(Date) as Out_time, Fisr_name, Last_name, Logical_code
from yourtable
where Date >= '2023-10-04 00:00:00' and 
      Date < '2023-10-05 00:00:00'
group by Fisr_name, Last_name, Logical_code
```